# how to make a trigger if time difference is 5 minutes then reset otp fill null

Tags: sql, laravel, triggers

**I need to make a trigger that will activate after a row is updated. When the time difference between updated_at and the current time is five (5) minutes then it will reset the OTP column into null.**

Here is my Table schema, my table name is **customers**.
[table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V98mI.jpg)

I have tried this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER 'ttl' AFTER 
UPDATE
   ON customers FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
      UPDATE
         TABLE customers 
         SELECT
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, updated_at, now()) > 5 
         SET
            otp = 0;
   END
```

It is not working

Comment: You need schedule a job.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is the update time when the row is updated?  If so, then that is the same time the trigger is called.  The condition is never met.  You cannot do this with a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

A before trigger can adjust the new.otp column before the update. https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_update.php Updating the real table in an update trigger of that table is not nice, could be an infinite loop.